# Orchard CMS adding an additional HTML part to page content type?

Tags: orchardcms

I'm trying to break my body into pre content, content, and post content so I can inject ads and what not within my articles. The only HTML field module is broken for 1.4 at the moment and I can't seem to add additional body parts to the page. I'm having to create my pre content in the body, then cut the HTML into a pre conntent text field. And do the same thing for post content. There's got to be a better way to do this. Is there any way to have more than one HTML editor field in the page editor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I told you in another answer, you can configure the Text field to use HTML. Just add the text field, and then expand it in the type editor. There is a drop-down where you can choose HTML.

Comment: Wow, I totally missed that little arrow next to the fields that opens a world of joy and sunshine. Thanks Bertrand, this is perfect!!

Comment: That's why it's always only gloom and rain here in Seattle: we give all of our joy and sunshine away :)